# Proof involving isomorphism and Annihilator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $F$. Show that

a) Let W be a subspace of $V$ and $x\in V\setminus W$. Then there is a $f\in A(W)$ with $f(x)\ne 0$.

b) Prove $A(A(W))=span(is(W))\subset V^{\lor\lor}=(V^\lor)^\lor$

$A$ is the annihilator and $is$ would be the isomorphism $is: V \rightarrow V^{\lor\lor}$

Definition of $A(W): \{f\in V^\lor |f(x)=0 \forall x \in W\}$

2nd EDIT: part a is rather easy i just didn't know how to prove it properly, but i defined a function to fulfill the condition so now it should work....Would be greatful if someone could give me a hint on b)

I dont quite understand $A(A(W))$ would be $A(0)$ right? So $A(0)$ is supposed to be the span of the transformation of the subset W?

3rd EDIT:

Could someone tell me for b) the difference between $V^{\lor\lor}$ and $(V^\lor)^\lor$....I could prove the first part...here i they are the same right?

Comment: Hi again, Jerry! You should put into your question your own thoughts/attempts, as well as other relevant info, as questions that simply state problems and nothing else are liable to be down-voted and closed. Do you know the definition of the annihilator? Also, while I have a reasonable guess as to what it means, the notation $V^\lor$ is not exactly standard. I also have a reasonable guess (based on my previous guess) as to the isomorphism $is$, but it's worth specifying, as isomorphisms tend not to be unique between isomorphic spaces. Any details you can put will help us answer.

Comment: @TheoBendit hello again haha i actually do i dont just post questions to get answers......this is a 5 part question i solved 3 on my own.....have somewhat of an answer for part a) too.....just part b i have no idea .... yeah this is the notation that i got from the university script.....I do this because i know it takes a while to get Hints/Answers so while i wait for some inputs i try to solve it myself.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $V^\lor$ is the (algebraic) dual space, i.e. the space of linear functionals (i.e. linear functions from $V$ to the scalar field $F$). In this case, $V^{\lor \lor}$ indeed means $(V^\lor)^\lor$. Further, I will assume that $is$ is the canonical injective linear map between $V$ and its second dual:
$$is(x) = (f \in V^\vee \mapsto f(x) \in F).$$
That is, the *point* $x \in V$ maps to the *function* from $V^\vee$ to $F$ that takes a linear functional $f$, and maps it to $f(x)$. Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, $V, V^\lor, V^{\lor\lor}$ have the same dimensions, so this linear map is not just injective, but an isomorphism.

> I don't quite understand $A(A(W))$ would be $A(0)$ right? So $A(0)$ is supposed to be the span of the transformation of the subset $W$?

No. It depends a little on which space the $0$ in $A(0)$ lies (in $V$? in $V^\lor$?). Really, only the latter makes sense, since $A(A(W)) \subseteq (V^\lor)^\lor$, and if $0 \in V$, then $A(0) \subseteq V^\lor$. But, even if $0 \in V^\lor$, it won't hold in general, as we will see in the following example.

Let's take $V = \Bbb{R}^2$ and $W = \operatorname{span}\{(1, 0)\}$. Let's suppose that $f \in V^\lor$. Then, $f$ takes the form, $f(x, y) = ax + by$ for some $a$ and $b$ (indeed, $a$ can be defined to be $f(1, 0)$ and $b$ to be $f(0, 1)$). Then, $f \in A(W)$ if and only if $0 = f(x, y) = ax + by$ for all $(x, y) \in W$. What does it mean to say $(x, y) \in W$? It means that $y = 0$, so $f \in A(W)$ if and only if
$$0 = f(x, 0) = ax + 0y = ax, \quad \forall x \in \Bbb{R}.$$
If we choose $x \neq 0$, then this implies $a = 0$, and so $f$ takes the form
$$f(x, y) = by.$$
Now, let's see what happens when we consider $\varphi \in A(A(W)) \subseteq (V^\lor)^\lor$. We know that all elements of $(V^\lor)^\lor$ can be written in the form $(f \mapsto f(x_0, y_0)) = is(x_0, y_0)$, for some $(x_0, y_0) \in \Bbb{R}^2$ (because $is$ is surjective, which heavily relies on $V$ being finite-dimensional). So, let's consider
\begin{align*}
is(x_0, y_0) \in A(A(W)) &\iff \forall f \in A(W),\,(is(x_0, y_0))(f) = 0 \\
&\iff \forall f \in A(W),\, f(x_0, y_0) = 0 \\
&\iff \forall b \in \Bbb{R},\, by_0 = 0 &\text{using the form of $f \in A(W)$} \\
&\iff y_0 = 0.
\end{align*}
So, not every vector $is(x_0, y_0)$ need be in $A(A(W))$. Indeed, the elements of $V$ are precisely the vectors of the form $is(x_0, 0)$. And, if you'll notice, this is precisely $is(W)$, i.e. the set of points obtained by applying $is$ to each point in $W$.

This cannot be $A(0)$, where $0 \in V^\lor$, as $A(0) = (V^\lor)^\lor$. Why? Because every linear functional in $(V^\lor)^\lor$ maps $0 \in V^\lor$ to $0 \in F$, purely by linearity. In the above example, we saw $A(A(W))$ was a proper subset of $(V^\lor)^\lor$.

Now, hopefully that example gives you a better grip on part b), as well as the double annihilator. To do the proof, use part a), maybe as part of a proof by contradiction (or by contrapositive). If $(x_0, y_0) \notin W$, then part a) would say...

Hope that helps. Let me know if you need more guidance.